# Visual Studio 2017 does not detect Windows Driver Kit installation

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, driver

I already have Visual Studio 2017 professional with Desktop Development with C++ installed.

I am trying to build the Virtual Serial project found here: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/serial/VirtualSerial

When I try to build it, I get the error: 
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

```
Error   MSB8020 The build tools for WindowsUserModeDriver10.0 (Platform Toolset = 'WindowsUserModeDriver10.0') cannot be found. To build using the WindowsUserModeDriver10.0 build tools, please install WindowsUserModeDriver10.0 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution".   virtualserial   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets
```

I cannot find any instructions on installation aside from this website.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk

I downloaded the WDK for `Windows 10, version 1803`. 
I closed VS2017 and ran the installer.

When running the installer I got the message in the screenshot below, I clicked `Next` to continue installing

After running the installer, the project still does not build, with the same error: `WindowsUserModeDriver10.0 is not installed`.

What am I missing during installation? Is this the correct installer for regular VS2017 (not community edition)?

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: have you installed the Win10 17134 SDK, too?

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, I installed vs2022 with SDK 19041 and WDK 19041.

After some testing, I realized that VS2022 only supports WDK 22621(so on this date). So I installed WDK 22621 and SDK 22621, and problem solved.

If you still can't find Kernel Driver Build option, try run this file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Vsix\VS2022\10.0.22621.0\WDK.vsix`(WDK 19041 only has `VS2019`). It's a Visual Studio's extension.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I recently fell into this rabbit hole. What worked for me was uninstalling all of the WDKs, rebooting, and installing WDK 1803 (the wdksetup.exe program downloaded from [Other WDK downloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/other-wdk-downloads) shows version 10.0.17134.1 in properties). That WDK installer specifically calls out VS 2017 when you add the Visual Studio integration at the end of the install process.

Answer (score -1):

According to this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware-winpc/windows-wdk-on-visual-studio-2017-community/fdbd2b44-e57a-4849-903d-04001205a764
WDK is not currently supported by visual studio 2017.
This is ridiculous

Comment: Well, that is a typical Answers answer.  I happened to install it just yesterday, worked fine.  Use Help > About to document your question with the VS2017 version number.  And Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem to let them know what went wrong.  Meanwhile use another machine.