# Visual studio 2019 cannot find Windows development kit

Tags: visual-studio, wdk

Trying to compile WireGuard-nt DLL provides an error saying visual studio cannot find the WDK.

Even after installing all available WDK’s visual studio will say it cannot find whichever the latest installed WDK is.

For example:
Visual studio could not find WDK 10.0.18361.0

Has anyone seen an issue like this before?

Thanks!

I tried installing all available WDK’s but visual studio kept providing the same error saying it could not find whichever latest installed version I installed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52320612/visual-studio-2017-does-not-detect-windows-driver-kit-installation

Comment: What was the version of the WDK and SDK you installed? In my experience they should be the same otherwise problems arise.